# Boosts say boost::log does not support forked processes. Is this still the case if the logger wasn't initialized until after the fork?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, fork

I have a process that forks, and then creates boost loggers, with different file names and different channel names *in each child process*.

Still, when I attempt to log anything, a deadlocks occur.  I don't see how it would matter if the logging was create/initialized AFTER the fork occurred.

```
child 1:
#0  in pthread_rwlock_wrlock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::lock() () from /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/x.so
#2  in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>::lock() const () from /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/x.so
#3  in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::exclusive_lock_guard<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::exclusive_lock_guard(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>&) () from /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/x.so
#4  in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::channel<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void> >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) () from /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/x.so

child 2:
#0  in pthread_rwlock_wrlock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::lock() () from /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/x.so
#2  in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>::lock() const () from /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/x.so
#3  in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::exclusive_lock_guard<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::exclusive_lock_guard(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>&) () from /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/x.so
#4  in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::channel<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void> >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) () from /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/x.so
```

Comment: Some kinds of static initializers will run before the `fork`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library has at least one non-trivial static initializer which runs before `main`. I did not trace everything that this initializes, but I expect it initializes a pthreads mutex which is then inherited upon fork. You could probably get away with logging from one child process, but logging from two fails because the shared state the `rwlock` maintains is not shared between the two child processes. One solution would be to move the boost logging and child code into a different executable and `fork` and `exec` that executable. Another possible solution would be to load boost logging dynamically, but that seems a bit complicated to do because of all the templates.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I will try to find a different logging library.